# Convert Text to Rows instead of Text to Columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a text string that is using the `^` symbol as a  delimiter.

I need to separate the text into new rows rather than new columns.

I need to create new rows to not overwrite the next line of data below it.

Is this possible without using a macro? I'm not against using one, I just wouldn't know where to start to write it.

Below is a pic of some sample data. The top part is how it's listed, and the bottom (in yellow) is how I would like it.

[image: Sample Data Pic]

Using Excel 2010 on Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: Thanks pnuts. I should have mentioned in my post that I've tried this approach. TtoC first and then transposing works when I only have a single text string with blank rows beneath it to transpose into. Unfortunately, it doesn't work when I have multiple strings in consecutive rows such as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those that responded. A friend was able to help by providing the following code:

```
Sub Breakout()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = LR To 2 Step -1
        Set MyCell = Cells(r, 1)
        Arry = Split(MyCell.Value, "^")
        For c = 0 To UBound(Arry)
            If c > 0 Then MyCell.Offset(c, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            MyCell.Offset(c, 0) = Arry(c)
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: If this code works for you, you should consider accepting it so other people can see and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this:

```
Sub reArrange()

    Dim inFirstRng As Range
    Dim inRng As Range
    Dim inCur As Variant
    Dim outFirstRng As Range
    Dim outCurRng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'CHANGE ARGUMENT TO YOUR SHEET NAME
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        'CHANGE ARGUMENT TO WHATEVER THE FIRST CELL OR YOUR DATA INPUT IS IN COLUMN A
        Set inFirstRng = .Range("A3")
        Set inRng = .Range(inFirstRng, inFirstRng.End(xlDown))
        'CHANGE ARGUMENT TO WHATEVER THE FIRST CELL OR YOUR DATA OUTPUT IS IN COLUMN A
        Set outFirstRng = .Range("A9")
        Set outCurRng = outFirstRng
    End With

    For Each cell In inRng.Cells

        inCur = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(cell.Value, "^"))
        outCurRng.Resize(UBound(inCur), 1).Value = inCur

        With ws
            .Range("G" & outCurRng.Row & ":L" & outCurRng.Row).Value = _
            .Range("G" & cell.Row & ":L" & cell.Row).Value
        End With

        Set outCurRng = outCurRng.Offset(UBound(inCur), 0)

    Next cell

    ws.Range("F" & outFirstRng.Row & ":F" & outCurRng.Row - 1).Value = 1

End Sub
```